# Sending Emails does not work in AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am trying to send emails through AWS. I have moved out of Sandbox and got the limit increase for US-WEST-2. I have verified my "from" email address,
 (Constants.FROM_EMAIL).

But still it looks for verification.

Error I am getting is,

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2: abc@gmail.com

I use below code.

```
    static final String SMTP_USERNAME = "my user name";
static final String SMTP_PASSWORD = "my password";

// Amazon SES SMTP host name. 
static final String HOST = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";    

static final int PORT = 25;


/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.email.AWSPostman#createProperties()
 */
public Properties createProperties() {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT); 

    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");

    return props;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.email.AWSPostman#createSession(java.util.Properties)
 */
public Session createSession(Properties props) {
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

    return session;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.email.AWSPostman#createTransport(javax.mail.Session)
 */
public Transport connectTransport(Session session) throws MessagingException {
    Transport transport = session.getTransport();
    transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);
    return transport;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.email.AWSPostman#closeTransport(javax.mail.Session)
 */
public void closeTransport(Transport transport) throws MessagingException {
    transport.close();
}

public Message createMessage(Session session, String to, String subject, String body) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
    // Create a message with the specified information. 
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Constants.FROM_EMAIL));
    msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setContent(body,"text/plain");

    return msg;
}

public void sendMessage(Transport transport, Message message) throws MessagingException {
    // Send the email.
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
}
```

Appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: Verify that your email address is not only verified, but verified for the region `us-west-2` that you specified.

Comment: Hi Anthony, it is (from 'email' address) verified for us-west-2. But above error is for "to" email.

Comment: `"But above error is for "to" email."` If this is correct, you are almost certainly still in SES sandbox mode for the `us-west-2` region. Sandbox mode requires both 'To' and 'From' addresses to be verified. SES sending limit increases are per-region; double check your configuration to verify that the exit from sandbox mode occurred in the region you expected.

Comment: Hi Anthony, AWS confirms to my request to move out from Sandbox is successful. Is there a way to check whether I am in sandbox or not? Also if I use verified emails for both "to" and "from", same code works.

Comment: Go to the AWS web console and make sure your region is set as `US West (Oregon)` in the top-right of the page, then navigate to the SES console. In the left navigation bar, under 'Email Sending', select 'Email Statistics'.  If you are in sandbox mode for this region, it should tell you on this page and prompt you to request a sending limit increase.

Comment: Hi Anthony.. I found the issue. I was using the credentials which I used when I was in sandbox. Tried by generating them again and it worked. Thank you for all suggestions above.